# Missing Product Category data post migration to Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

We recently upgraded a site from Google Analytics classic to Universal Analytics.

In classic the Product Performance report had a dimension for "Product Category" in Universal the Product Performance report has a dimension of "Product Category(enhanced eCommerce)".

Selecting Product Category (enhanced eCommerce) for a period of time before the migration returns no data however we know that this data was available and used regularly before.

All the articles and documentation I have read has stated that there would be no data loss when migrating.

Is there a way to view the old Product category dimension post migration to UA?

Comment: It sounds to me that the product category from standard ecom isn't the same as the Enhanced Ecom product category, in the sense that the data doesn't get processed in the same way so that that information is not migrated over. Can you link to the articles you mentioned?

Comment: I found the article following the post - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77512/switching-to-google-universal-analytics-data-loss?rq=1 unfortunately the Google Documentation referenced no longer makes any mention with regards to Data-Loss at all.